# Referencing functions from within functions inside a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var Page = {
    data: null,
    Load: function () {
        this.Populate;
    },
    Populate: function () {
    }
};

$(document).ready(Page.Load);
```

1. Why can't I reference `Page.Load` as a function in `ready()` eg `.ready(Page.Load())`
2. Why can't I call `this.Populate()` from the Load function, I just get `this.Populate()` is not a function.

Comment: You're not making our lives any easier with a confusing title.

Comment: @BoltClock Yo dawg! We heard you like queries so we put a query in your jQuery so you can query while jQuery-ing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First, as Rob says, you're not actually calling the `Populate()` method in `Load()`. You need to add parenthesis to do that.

Second, the `this` keyword in `Populate()` does not refer to the `Page` object. You can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set the `Page` object as the context of the method call:

```
var Page = {
    data: null,
    Load: function() {
        this.Populate();
    },
    Populate: function() {
    }
};

$(document).ready($.proxy(Page.Load, Page));
```

Comment: Wow! All answers really useful!  I love Stack Overflow.

Comment: went for this answer as it seems more jquery and is smaller in code :)

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't I reference Page.Load as a function in ready() eg .ready(Page.Load())

Sticking `()` on the end **calls** a function. You want to pass the function itself, not its return value. (The `ready` function will call what you pass to it later).

> Why can't I call this.Populate() from the Load function, I just get this.Populate() is not a function

Two reasons.

First, you never actually call the Populate function. Change to:

```
this.Populate()
```

Second: because you detach the Load function from the object, so `this` isn't `Page` by the time it gets called.

Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () { Page.Load() });
```

Answer (score 3):

A function call should be in the format `function_name()` (parentheses!). A function reference should be `function_name` (without parentheses). This code will work:

```
var Page = {
    data: null,
    Load: function () {
        Page.Populate(); //PARENTHESES
    },
    Populate: function () {
    }
};

$(document).ready(Page.Load);//NO PARENTHESES
```

`$(document).ready` is a function which expects a function to be parameter 1. If you use `Page.Load()`, you will execute function `Page.Load()` and pass the return value (`undefined`, in this case) to `$(document).ready`.

Comment: `this.Populate();` will not work - `this` is set by jQuery to be the `window`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot to mention that this.Populate works but this.Populate() doesn't.  I have updated my question. Sorry about that

Comment: @Kobi Thanls for mentioning. `this.Populate` doesn't work, because `.ready(Page.load)` executes the function argument within the scope of JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to work by wrapping your object up in a function like this:

```
var Page = (function () {
    var that = {
        data: null,
        Load: function () {
            that.Populate(); 
        },
        Populate: function () {
            alert("Test");
        }
    };
    return that;
})(); // Execute the function immediately to return 'that'

$(document).ready(Page.Load);
```

This way you can call between methods as you have a reference to the object (that).

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/efaqal/edit#source)

Comment: Thanks Richard, Im going to use Frederic's answer with the proxy.

Comment: np, feel free to upvote mine though because it's obviously awesome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function Page.Load.  But more specifically you're calling the function that Page.Load is set to (since that argument to .ready() is just a simple value); you're *not* calling it *on* Page, so 'this' is not reset to point to the Page object.

This will work better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Page.Load();
});
```